# global variable, child process and parent process

Tags: linux

I have a question actually I didn't understand something about child and parent processes.When I change a global variable inside child process, these changes don't effect parent process. I saw a sentence on this web site. It says: "modifying any variables in the parent or child will not see the changes also being made to the other one." Could you please give more information? Thank you.

Comment: By the way, I read another comment. It says child process and parent process have different spaces in memory this is why changes do not effect. I don't know if it is true or not.

Comment: Processes do not share the same virtual memory address space, therefore they cannot access each other's variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are getting confused with the difference between a **process** and a **thread**.

A **process** can contain multiple threads. A process has its own address space and system variables (such as file handles). Processes can only interact through IPC mechanisms, and cannot directly touch another processes variables otherwise. Every process has a PID that the OS uses to identify it (at least in linux). Processes can have many threads running on top of the process.

A **thread** is a unique construct that can run inside a process. Each thread has its own unique stack pointer (which points to the assembly executing) and unique registry values. When the OS switches between threads, it switches the current line of execution and restores all the resgistry values stored with that thread. However, threads in a process share all the same memory, which is why you can modify global and class variables between threads and they are affected.

If anyone wants to chime in they can. This is just a brief summary of what I think are some of the important points between understanding the difference between processes and threads.

Comment: I understood what you are saying. So I can have 1 process but inside it, there can be multiple threads and they share same memory space that's why changes will affect all. Ok I got it. Thanks!

Comment: @AhmetTanakol You should accept answers if they are helpful to you. I've noticed you haven't accepted for any questions you've asked.

Answer (score 2):

After the fork() is called, the exact replica of parent is created.(well, not really. Read manpage for details) So, the child and parent both have separate process tables & different address space. Hence the statement, `modifying any variables in the parent or child will not see the changes also being made to the other one.`

Please read the [manpage of fork()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) for the exact details.